# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'graph' in Style Transfer program

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting the error  AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'graph' while running the Style Transfer algorithm.

I am using Python 3.6, tensorflow 1.10.0.

Can anyone help me to fix the issue.

Error Message:

in style_transfer(content_image, style_image, content_layer_ids, style_layer_ids, weight_content, weight_style, weight_denoise, num_iterations, step_size)
     30 
     31     # Create a TensorFlow-session.
---> 32     session = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=model.graph)
     33 
     34     # Print the names of the content-layers.

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'graph'

Answer (score 0):

can you show me what that 'model' variable is?

A session however tf.Session() has a graph.
If it is a keras model (wild assumption)
do:

`keras.backend.get_session().graph`

or even:

`with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
     tf.summary.FileWriter("foldername", sess.graph)`